Redirect the stderr of a socat fork to separate process
I have a python program that is accessed via socat, so that stdin and stdout are provided and displayed on a client.  I use:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"python prompt.py"

This works as expected.  prompt.py displays some info on stderr which shows up on the server side.  Instead I would like stderr to be sent to a logging process on a third server (so not the client that connects to the above socat).  I can do the stderr part as expected (without socat) using:
python prompt.py 2> >(nc -q 0 logger 2323)

In this case I can read/answer the prompt on the terminal running this command, and stderr goes to logger which is running:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:2323,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"tee -a errors.txt"

and errors.txt fills up as expected.  But when I try to combine these with:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"python prompt.py 2> >(nc -q 0 logger 2323)",pty

stderr of the python prompt.py is not sent as expected; instead, it is still shown on the server.  I also tried:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"bash -c 'python prompt.py 2> >(nc -q 0 logger 2323)'"

With this nothing seems to happen when connecting to socat.  Why does the EXEC of my bash command or python command not run the stderr redirection?Is there a way to do this?
I have tried redirecting stderr of the socat command instead; however, this opens and keeps open the nc connection which I did not want.  I wanted the nc connection to be opened and then closed each time the python program is ran.

Socats EXEC address uses the execvp() system call that executes the command directly. However, your various redirects need to be interpreted by a shell.
You might try the SYSTEM address instead that uses the system() call, but it uses /bin/sh instead of bash (or any other modern shell) and only understands simple redirects like ">" or ">2"
There are two workarounds:

Have EXEC invoke bash expicitely; this, however, requires escaping of quotes and blanks to get the execvp() arguments right:


socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"bash -c \\\"python\ prompt.py\ 2>\ >(nc\ -q\ 0\ logger\ 2323)\\\"",pty


Use the SHELL address (new with Socat 1.8!), it does the EXEC:"bash -c ..." trick implicitely:


socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork SHELL:"python prompt.py 2> >(nc -q 0 logger 2323)",pty

